# How to remove top cliques with nodes

Tags: python, networkx

So I have used [clustering](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html#clustering) to get the clustering coefficient for all the nodes in the graph, like this

```
G=nx.complete_graph(40)
clus_coeff = nx.clustering(G)
```

Now I want to remove **the largest sized cliques** containing these nodes. I just want to remove the cliques with Top 5 nodes ordered by clustering coefficient. I am not exactly sure how to proceed

Comment: can you share some more working code? what have you tried and what is not working for you